# Mini Test and Rails 6: Re-use variables on different tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd, minitest

How do you declare a variable that can persist on different tests? For example I have the following

```
setup do 
  @payload = {...}
  @another_payload = {...}
end
```

on one controller, I end up copying them to a different controller if I need to use them, is there a way to make them persist across tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Concern](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.0/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) to do this:

```rb
# test/supports/payload_setup.rb
module PayloadSetup
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    setup do 
      @payload = {...}
      @another_payload = {...}
    end
  end
end

# some_test.rb
class SomeTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  include PayloadSetup

  test 'some test' do
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Im new tyo this so wans't so familiar, it works, thanks!